# Bank App Extension for iMessage

Tags: ios, p2p, ios-app-extension, imessage

I would like to know if the iMessage SDK on iOS 11 supports P2P Payments  via third-party apps (a bank app for instance) or is this restricted to the Apple Pay Cash feature ? In other words, is it possible to develop a bank app extension in iMessage to enable P2P money transfer using the bank back-end system.

Comment: yes it does support those types of payment apps. Just look at the likes of PingIt

Comment: Can you tell if it is supported in France also ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an iMessage Extension

> **iMessage extension.**
>
> An iMessage extension can include the same features as a standalone
>   iMessage app, and allow users to access features of your iOS app
>   without leaving Messages. Your iMessage app will be listed on the App
>   Store for iMessage in the same category and with the same description
>   as your iOS app on the App Store.

An extension can provide shared functionality of your iOS application.

Banks in the UK have started to implement this functionality already. This should be available to anyone regardless of location as it's part of the SDK.